# Questions on Gson and Java model class

Tags: java, gson, android

I am using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for converting between json and java object.

Let's say the json is like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 12,
    "adult": false
}
```

The class for the json is:

```
public class Student {
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private boolean adult;

  // setters for all fields above
  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
  ...

  // getters for all fields above
  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }
  ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it so that all fields showing in json should have @Expose annotation? Does that also mean we can have other fields which are not part of the json string?
2. Is it so that only if the field name in json and the variable name in java class is different, then use @SerializedName annotation is needed, otherwise it is optional?
3. Are **setter** functions necessary in java class for the fields?

Answer (score 0):

The short answers to your questions are 1. yes, 2. yes, 3. no.

`Gson` has a lot going on under the hood - your Student class needs very little for it to do its work:

- data members which match the key values in the JSON (case-sensitive!)
- public getter methods

You can have more data members that don't necessarily match the key names in the JSON, they'll just end up getting set to `null` when `Gson` processes the data. `Gson` also does not require any annotations so long as the variable names match the key names in the JSON. You are allowed to have any kind of setter methods if you need them for other functionality (`Gson` does not). Basically, the only thing that `Gson` is looking for is data members that match the keys, and the getter methods. Whether your class is more complex is up to you and what your application needs.

**edit**: All of the values that `Gson` processes will be of the `String` type. If you have `int` and `boolean` types you will need to process the input as a `String` and operate on it to convert it to what you are looking for.

Comment: `If you have int and boolean types you will need to process the input as a String and operate on it to convert it to what you are looking for.`  Could you please provide a example(code snippet) how to do it?